# Kinesis Java consumer failing to post or get messages using sdk 2.0

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, nio, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-agent

I have followed https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/streams/latest/dev/kcl2-standard-consumer-java-example.html to write a simple java kinesis client.The credentials used have full admin access.
When executing the code getting the below error.

```
22:16:56.875 [aws-java-sdk-NettyEventLoop-2-5] WARN io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline - An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.
io.netty.channel.ChannelPipelineException: com.typesafe.netty.http.HttpStreamsHandler$1.handlerRemoved() has thrown an exception.
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.callHandlerRemoved0(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:676)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.remove(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:505)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.remove(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:451)
    at com.typesafe.netty.http.HttpStreamsHandler.removeHandlerIfActive(HttpStreamsHandler.java:328)
    at com.typesafe.netty.http.HttpStreamsHandler.handleReadHttpContent(HttpStreamsHandler.java:189)
    at com.typesafe.netty.http.HttpStreamsHandler.channelRead(HttpStreamsHandler.java:165)
    at com.typesafe.netty.http.HttpStreamsClientHandler.channelRead(HttpStreamsClientHandler.java:148)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.http.nio.netty.internal.http2.Http2ToHttpInboundAdapter.onDataRead(Http2ToHttpInboundAdapter.java:75)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.http.nio.netty.internal.http2.Http2ToHttpInboundAdapter.channelRead0(Http2ToHttpInboundAdapter.java:51)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.http.nio.netty.internal.http2.Http2ToHttpInboundAdapter.channelRead0(Http2ToHttpInboundAdapter.java:42)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1434)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.ForkedHttp2MultiplexCodec$DefaultHttp2StreamChannel$Http2ChannelUnsafe.doRead0(ForkedHttp2MultiplexCodec.java:972)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.ForkedHttp2MultiplexCodec$DefaultHttp2StreamChannel$Http2ChannelUnsafe.beginRead(ForkedHttp2MultiplexCodec.java:941)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.read(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1386)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:693)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.read(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:673)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.read(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:95)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:693)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.read(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:673)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.read(ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.java:93)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:693)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.read(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:673)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.read(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:95)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:693)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.read(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:673)
    at com.typesafe.netty.HandlerPublisher.requestDemand(HandlerPublisher.java:86)
    at com.typesafe.netty.http.HttpStreamsHandler$1.requestDemand(HttpStreamsHandler.java:157)
    at com.typesafe.netty.HandlerPublisher.channelReadComplete(HandlerPublisher.java:384)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelReadComplete(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:398)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelReadComplete(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:380)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelReadComplete(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:373)
    at com.typesafe.netty.http.HttpStreamsHandler.channelReadComplete(HttpStreamsHandler.java:214)
    at com.typesafe.netty.http.HttpStreamsClientHandler.channelReadComplete(HttpStreamsClientHandler.java:30)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelReadComplete(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:398)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelReadComplete(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:380)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelReadComplete(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:373)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelReadComplete(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:97)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelReadComplete(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:398)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelReadComplete(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:380)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelReadComplete(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:373)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelReadComplete(IdleStateHandler.java:295)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelReadComplete(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:398)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelReadComplete(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:380)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelReadComplete(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:373)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelReadComplete(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1439)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelReadComplete(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:398)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelReadComplete(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:380)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelReadComplete(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:971)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.ForkedHttp2MultiplexCodec$DefaultHttp2StreamChannel$Http2ChannelUnsafe.beginRead(ForkedHttp2MultiplexCodec.java:954)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.read(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1386)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:693)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.read(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:673)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.read(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:95)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:693)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.read(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:673)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.read(ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.java:93)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:693)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.read(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:673)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.read(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:95)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:693)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.read(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:673)
    at com.typesafe.netty.HandlerPublisher.requestDemand(HandlerPublisher.java:86)
    at com.typesafe.netty.http.HttpStreamsHandler$1.requestDemand(HttpStreamsHandler.java:157)
    at com.typesafe.netty.HandlerPublisher.receivedDemand(HandlerPublisher.java:271)
    at com.typesafe.netty.HandlerPublisher.access$200(HandlerPublisher.java:41)
    at com.typesafe.netty.HandlerPublisher$ChannelSubscription$1.run(HandlerPublisher.java:452)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute$$$capture(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:464)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NO_INTS
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.cbor.CBORParser.<init>(CBORParser.java:285)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.cbor.CBORParserBootstrapper.constructParser(CBORParserBootstrapper.java:91)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.cbor.CBORFactory._createParser(CBORFactory.java:350)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.cbor.CBORFactory.createParser(CBORFactory.java:287)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.cbor.CBORFactory.createParser(CBORFactory.java:26)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.http.JsonResponseHandler.handle(JsonResponseHandler.java:91)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.BaseClientHandler.lambda$interceptorCalling$2(BaseClientHandler.java:122)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.AttachHttpMetadataResponseHandler.handle(AttachHttpMetadataResponseHandler.java:41)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.AttachHttpMetadataResponseHandler.handle(AttachHttpMetadataResponseHandler.java:29)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.async.SyncResponseHandlerAdapter.complete(SyncResponseHandlerAdapter.java:92)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.BaseAsyncClientHandler$InterceptorCallingHttpResponseHandler.complete(BaseAsyncClientHandler.java:225)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.MakeAsyncHttpRequestStage$ResponseHandler.handleResponse(MakeAsyncHttpRequestStage.java:182)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.MakeAsyncHttpRequestStage$ResponseHandler.complete(MakeAsyncHttpRequestStage.java:171)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.MakeAsyncHttpRequestStage$ResponseHandler.complete(MakeAsyncHttpRequestStage.java:122)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.http.nio.netty.internal.ResponseHandler$PublisherAdapter$1.onComplete(ResponseHandler.java:262)
    at com.typesafe.netty.HandlerPublisher.complete(HandlerPublisher.java:408)
    at com.typesafe.netty.HandlerPublisher.handlerRemoved(HandlerPublisher.java:395)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.callHandlerRemoved0(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:670)
    ... 85 common frames omitted
```

It also goes for initializing LeaseCoordinator

```
22:16:42.415 [Thread-1] INFO software.amazon.kinesis.coordinator.Scheduler - Initialization attempt 1
22:16:42.415 [Thread-1] INFO software.amazon.kinesis.coordinator.Scheduler - Initializing LeaseCoordinator
22:16:42.451 [Thread-1] DEBUG software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.interceptor.ExecutionInterceptorChain - Creating an interceptor chain that will apply interceptors in the following order: []
```

Tried everywhere and found no leads.
I am using the latest lib

```
<dependency>
<groupId>software.amazon.kinesis</groupId>
<artifactId>amazon-kinesis-client</artifactId>
<version>2.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Fixed it. Had to exclude Google Guava from other lib and use the one in the kinesis client.

Comment: Are you able to use enhanced fan-out feature ? (HTTP2)